# Parsing/processing Burpsuite Intruder responses automatically?

Tags: burp-suite, fuzzing

So, testing some command injection fuzzing in Burp using Intruder, and each of the responses generated are around 10k with 99.5% of them being identical between each request.

Is there a way to automatically filter out responses, a la sed, so that what I am left with in the response window are the unique contents of the query?

So lets say Im fuzzing "data" parameter in http://blah.co.uk/input.php?data=foo, and the response is:

```
<html>
<body>

this data field is constant across all fuzzing attempts
so is this one
however this one is unique to the data field, user foo

</body>

</html>
```

I want to be able to view the 'response' window and see nothing but:

```
however this one is unique to the data field, user foo
```

Is there a simpler resolution path than writing a plugin from scratch?

Comment: It's in the options tab for Intruder - you can extract parts of the response based on patterns or positions within it.